# JSoup - How to compare the similarity of 2 tables

Tags: html-table, compare, jsoup, similarity

I'm new in JSoup. I don't know there are any methods for compare similarity 2 tables (or 2 elements as well) in JSoup.

To be specific, suppose that I have 2 tables below:
    
    
    1
    2
    3

```
</table>

<table>
<tr>
<td>1</td>
<td>2</td>
<td>3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>4</td>
<td>5</td>
<td>6</td>
</tr>

</table>
```

So, how I determine that 2 tables might is similar?

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way if you except tables to be 100% similar, then you can do following:

```
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(yourDocumentHtml);       
if(doc.select("table#table1").text().equals(doc.select("table#table2").text()) && doc.select("table#table1").outerHtml().equals(doc.select("table#table2").outerHtml()) )
{
    // Tables are equal
}
else
{
    // Tables are not equal
}
```